# Custom roles and permission in GitLab CE

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

Is there any possible ways to create a custom role in gitlab CE, I am using 13.12v.
Objective is to have multi level of approval between developer and maintainer like sprint_reviewer, release_reviewer.
These two reviewer will have access to merge any branch on sprint and release branch respectively.

If my question is not clear kindly let me know.

I have tried using UI but there is no option to achieve so, I tried to modify the gitlab source file but unable to found the correct file and details